# Google Appengine convert string to text

Tags: android, string, google-app-engine, text, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to convert a string to a text since I hit an error on appengine that said my strings were too long.  Here is the code:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;

public void setItems(String itemList) {
    this.items = new Text(itemList);
}
```

But appengine shows the value of items as [object Object].

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text) seems to say my approach is correct but clearly I'm missing something (probably simple).

After a little more experimenting I determined that

```
zt.setItems("test string")
```

works correctly but when I upload zt to appengine using

```
public void insertTheme(Theme theme) {
ofy().save().entity(uccwtheme).now();
}
```

Then if I open the entity in Cloud Datastore I see the value of items is [object Object]

More:

So if I open Theme.java (the compiled class) in the middle of debugging, the method setItems shows:

```
/**
* Model definition for Theme.
*
 * <p> This is the Java data model class that specifies how to parse/serialize into the     JSON that is
 * transmitted over HTTP when working with the themeendpoint. For a detailed explanation see:
* <a href="http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON">http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON</a>
* </p>
*
* @author Google, Inc.
*/


  /**
   * @param themeItems themeItems or {@code null} for none
*/
  public Theme setItems(java.lang.String items) {
this.items = items;
return this;
}
```

What happened to Text?  And why did the return type change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, so I'm an idiot.  Appengine stores Text as an object and that's why it can't be viewed in Cloud Console.  If I had tried to actually download the theme I would have seen there was a value for items that matched what I uploaded.

Way to waste multiple hours :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename one of the "items" to something else. For example,

```
this.items = new Text(itemsString);
```